# Oracle SQL: Duplicate rows when trying to query data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Table A:

| Plant ID | Plant Name | Unit Name | Technology Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | Unit 1 | SMR |
| 1 | ABC | Unit 2 | Electrolysis |

Table B:

| Plant ID | Feedstock Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Natural Gas |
| 1 | Water |

```
select
a.PLANT_NAME,
a.UNIT_NAME,
b.FEEDSTOCK_TYPE,
a.TECHNOLOGY_TYPE

from
Table A a
inner join Table B b
on a.plant_ID = b.plant_ID
```

When I run the code, the result will be

| Plant Name | Unit Name | Technology Type | Feedstock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Unit 1 | SMR | Natural Gas |
| ABC | Unit 1 | SMR | Water |
| ABC | Unit 2 | Electrolysis | Natural Gas |
| ABC | Unit 2 | Electrolysis | Water |

But I expect the result to be

| Plant Name | Unit Name | Technology Type | Feedstock Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Unit 1 | SMR | Natural Gas |
| ABC | Unit 2 | Electrolysis | Water |

The problem is I dont have a common primary key to link each unit to each feedstock. I only have one common plant id between the 2 tables. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Supplied solutions are good but I think you must rethink your database because if you have only one field to link two tables, you have this result. Maybe you must add a foreign key field to pint your plantID so the primary key of table B is different. So you can take only the MAX id or other logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nothing to `join` on beyond the `plant_id`.  If you want to "align" the rows, you can introduce a new column using `row_number()`:

```
select a.PLANT_NAME, a.UNIT_NAME, b.FEEDSTOCK_TYPE, a.TECHNOLOGY_TYPE
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by plant_id order by unit_name) as seqnum
      from table_A a
     ) a join
     (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by plant_id order by feedstock_type) as seqnum
      from table_B b
     ) b
     on a.plant_ID = b.plant_ID and a.seqnum = b.seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it as there's no way to distinguish whether to take "Natural Gas" or "Water" as both values share the same `PLANT_ID` in `table_B`.

You *can* take one of them using an aggregate function, e.g. `MAX`, but that's just a *workaround* which doesn't return what you wanted anyway. For example (sample data in lines #1 - 9) (note `MAX` in line #12 which also requires the `GROUP BY` clause):

```
SQL> with
  2  table_a (plantid, plant_name, unit_name, technology_type) as
  3    (select 1, 'ABC', 'Unit 1', 'SMR'          from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'ABC', 'Unit 2', 'Electrolysis' from dual
  5    ),
  6  table_b (plantid, feedstock_type) as
  7    (select 1, 'Natural Gas' from dual union all
  8     select 1, 'Water'       from dual
  9    )
 10  select a.plant_name,
 11         a.unit_name,
 12         max(b.feedstock_type) feedstock_type,
 13         a.technology_type
 14  from table_a a join table_b b on a.plantid = b.plantid
 15  group by a.plant_name, a.unit_name, a.technology_type;

PLA UNIT_NAME  FEEDSTOCK_TYPE  TECHNOLOGY_TYPE
--- ---------- --------------- ---------------
ABC Unit 2     Water           Electrolysis
ABC Unit 1     Water           SMR

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no implicit values in a table, only explicit ones in columns.  You appear to want to join "row 1" of table A to "row 1" of table B, and so on.  In that case you need an explicit value 1, 2, ... in column in each table and join on that.